# Django: How to access originating instance from a RelatedManager?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I would like to access the `Foo` instance `foo` within my manager method `baz`:

```
foo.bar_set.baz()
```

`baz` would normally take an argument of `Foo` type:

```
BarManager(models.Manager):
    def baz(self, foo=None):
        if foo is None:
            # assume this call originates from
            # a RelatedManager and set `foo`.
            # Otherwise raise an exception
        # do something cool with foo
```

This way both the first query above and the following one works identically:

```
Bar.objects.baz(foo)
```

`Bar` would have a ForeignKey to `Foo`:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    objects = BarManager()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, you need to do this:

```
 BarManager(models.Manager):
      use_for_related_fields = True
```

**Edit:** apparently I managed to miss the point completely. You can use something like this (maybe a bit too "magic" for my taste, but oh well):

```
class BarManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def bar(self, foo=None):
        if foo == None:
            qs = Foo.objects.all()
            for field_name, field_val in self.core_filters.items():
                field_name = field_name.split('__')[1]
                qs = qs.filter(**{ field_name: field_val })
            foo = qs.get()
        # do k00l stuff with foo
```

Comment: No, that's not necessary. baz method is already available on Foo.bar_set

Answer (score 2):

In Django 2.1 at least, you can simply do:

`foo.bar_set.instance`